# Find $x$ when $(x+1)^4 + (x-1)^4 = 272$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find $x$ if $(x+1)^4 + (x-1)^4 = 272.$

---

I was thinking of setting $y = x + 2,$ but that got real ugly real fast. Is there a better way to do this problem then?

Comment: Are you told that there are integer solutions:?  If so, it's obvious which integers to test.   Otherwise, note that this equation expands to $2x^4+12x^2+2=272$ which is quadratic in $z=x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since odd factors cancel out, by Pascal's triangle for $n=4$ that is $(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)$, we have that

$$(x+1)^4 + (x-1)^4 = 272$$

$$2(x^4+6x^2+1) = 272$$

$$x^4+6x^2-135 = 0 \iff x=\pm 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$x=\pm 3$ or $x=\pm i\sqrt {15}$

Answer (score 0):

The left side is a convex function and the right side is a constant.

Thus, our equation has two real roots maximum.

But $3$ and $-3$ are roots and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

> Find a solution to $(x+1)^4 + (x-1)^4 = 272$.

Consider,

$a + b = 272$.

If $a = b$, $ a = 136$.

OK,

$\quad 2^4 = 016 < 136$
$\quad 3^4 = 081 < 136$
$\quad 4^4 = 256 > 136$

Since $272 = 16 + 256$ we get a solution, $ x = 3$.